# How to delay jquery prop(,) with no extra function

Tags: jquery, html, delay, timing, benchmarking

I have some radio buttons that i want to change which one is checked with jQuery all the time half a second after an image is faded, without adding any extra function, this is my code:

```
$("#myImage").fadeOut(1000);
$("#myRadioInput").delay(500).prop("checked",true)
```

Why doesn't it work as i want?

Comment: `prop` doesn't used queue so you need to use additional methods

Comment: @Satpal , so i cant achieve that with no extra function?

Comment: Yep, even jQuery document says `.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.` Go through docs https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: such a pity!:D!ok thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is non blocking. Those functions will practically be called at the same time. You can see your example here:

```js
$("#doIt").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#myDiv").fadeOut(1000);
  $("#myRadioInput").delay(500).prop("checked", true);

})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="doIt">Do It!</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input id="myRadioInput" type="checkbox">
```

Also, [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) does not function as you expect. It *does not* "pause" the chain. It adds a delay to a queue, normally `fx`, which *would* allow you to pause further animations, but not pause the next call in your chain. You can see examples of this in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

In the question, you say:

> without adding any extra function

I don't understand the motivation behind this requirement. The obvious solution is to use "extra" functions. We are programming after all ;)

```js
$("#doIt").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#myDiv").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#myRadioInput").delay(500).prop("checked", true);
    }, 500);
  });

})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="doIt">Do It!</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input id="myRadioInput" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: the motive before that is being a student before being a programmer and having desire to learn!so i have desire to know if there is a way to achieve that without defining any function.and also i guess it will make the site lighter:)

Comment: and!i'm sry, i didn't understand the first part of your answer, but if it helps, they are both inside one another function:)

Answer (score 0):

you have to include your 1000ms fading time, because your 500ms delay time starts counting at start of fading:

```
$("#myImage").fadeOut(1000);
$("#myRadioInput").delay(1500).prop("checked",true);
```

**OR** start counting after `fadeOut()` function end:

```
$("#myImage").fadeOut(1000,function(){
  $("#myRadioInput").delay(500).prop("checked",true);
});
```

Comment: As I said, I want to extra function to be defined.otherwise it could have easily been achieved using setTimeout.